# What is the most efficient websocket message size?

Tags: websocket, cloudflare-workers

I have a client running in Chrome (V8), and a web server also running V8 (not Node; a Cloudflare worker).

The server only supports receiving WebSocket messages of maximum size 1MB.

I have a fetch running on the client that uses a ReadableStream and needs to forward the bytes over a WebSocket to the server.

The chunk size of the ReadableStream could differ and seems to be undefined.

The question: is it more efficient for the server process to receive many small WebSocket messages, or the same amount of bytes batched into larger WebSocket messages?

I would assume the larger WebSocket messages are more effective as it would mean less event loop events, less function calls, and less variables for the GC.

But I cannot find any information online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's probably technically true that bigger chunks will increase throughput, there are diminishing returns at such large sizes. On the other hand, bigger chunks are worse for latency, because the sender cannot start sending the chunk until it has produced the whole thing, and the recipient cannot begin processing the chunk until it has received the whole thing. Also, big chunks lead to more bursty CPU usage, while small chunks will allow smoother CPU usage, even if the total CPU usage is greater overall. Big chunks can also drive up peak memory usage.

To find the optimal chunk size for any particular application, you'd need to carefully benchmark that app. However, no one has time for that. Personally, I would normally choose a chunk size between 8k and 64k. Probably would lean towards 64k for this use case.